# Is there a mnemonic that helps remembering when I should use "hate," and when "ate"?

Tags: spelling, confusable, mnemonic

Being an Italian native speaker, I sometimes write *ate* when I should have written *hate*, and vice versa.

Is there a mnemonic I could use to remember when I should write *ate*, and when *hate*?

Comment: I think, you should give us a hint. Since Italian has no glottal consonants, how the children are taught in schools to pronounce them?

Comment: In the case of _house_ the pronunciation is probably compared to the one of _casa_ ("house") in Tuscan. (Tuscan is particular, as _c_ in _casa_ is not pronounced [k].)

Comment: Heh, this is a *perfect* question for this site. As a native speaker, my first reaction was "why on earth would anyone ever confuse these two words? In what alien universe do they sound interchangeable?" But then I realized that some dialects/languages don't use the 'h' sound.

Comment: @Martha When I went to elementary school, the _h_ was called the silent letter. That says all. `;)`

Comment: (offtopic mode on) @Martha Some languages have [up to eight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_phonology#Consonants) velar/uvular/epiglottal/glottal consonant sounds. For an English speaker, they all sound between /k/ and /h/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a *well known* mnemonic, I think because it's not usually a cause of confusion to native listeners.  To help, I'd suggest the following:

- *ate* is an anagram of *eat*
- *hate* is tattooed on the fingers of one fist, *love* is tattooed on the other (if you're a biker, seaman, etc).

Comment: you almost had a mnemonic there...ate is anagram of eat, hate is an anagram of heat... hmm... if you don't pronounce the 'h' in either case that would still be a problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: "There isn't a mnemonic..." Uh, sure there is. There are several provided as answers here (including your own).

Comment: The first is much more helpful. Once I remember when to write _ate_, I remember also when to write _hate_.

Answer (score 3):

### Self Composed?

These are self-composed mnemonics.

> When *hate* hated itself, it *ate* the **h**.

or

> I *hate* pronouncing **h**, so I *ate* it.

Comment: Sounds good! What about some improvement? "I *hate* pronouncing /h/, so I *ate* it"

Comment: Awesome! I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, try to think of "ate" as "hate" with the "H" eaten.